# How to disable in place blogs editing in Liferay 6.2

Tags: ckeditor, liferay, liferay-6

Liferay 6.2 introduces in-place editing for blogs portlet with ckeditor. Is there any way to disable it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To disable blog inline editing you need to create a hook for blog and override `"view_entry_content.jsp"` file. In this file find `boolean` variable `"inlineEditEnabled"` and change its value to false. Just a note that this change will get applied to across site/portal.

To Overcome this, You can create a display style in asset publisher and override this jsp only when your display style has been selected. This approach will give you an option were you can have a blog with edit enable functionality as well.

HTH

Comment: Thank you. I think it would be useful to make this available from a portal.properties parameter.

Comment: @CarlosCes Can you please hightlight what was missing on above answer? Since you unmarked it as answer I am curious to know the reason behind it. If something is missing in above answer I would like to hear.

Comment: It was not intended. I must have pressed it not in purpouse, sorry for that.

Answer (score 4):

About :-
Remove Inline editing for blogs to activate link

Go to your liferay portal folder.
In that change in : 
liferay-portal folder⇒ tomcat-7.0.42 ⇒ webapps ⇒ ROOT ⇒ html ⇒ portlet ⇒ blogs ⇒ view_entry_content.jsp

Search code :

**boolean inlineEditEnabled = BlogsEntryPermission.contains(permissionChecker, entry, ActionKeys.UPDATE) && BrowserSnifferUtil.isRtf(request) && !WorkflowDefinitionLinkLocalServiceUtil.hasWorkflowDefinitionLink(themeDisplay.getCompanyId(), scopeGroupId, BlogsEntry.class.getName());**

After this code just add this line within <% %>.

> inlineEditEnabled=false;